# Warning "Remove the file from everyone's Dropbox" in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, dropbox

I'm working on some basic maps in ArcGIS Pro and am using Dropbox as my storage. These files are accessible to other folks who are also working on the same project. I have been receiving messages from Dropbox asking the following:

[image]

I'm not trying to delete or move this aprx. I'm changing symbology or maybe editing a field -- normal, basic GIS stuff.

I can hit cancel and everything is cool, but it's annoying and I have a tiny fear that I will absent mindedly not hit cancel. I don't think others have the file open at the same time and even so, I've dealt with the "Conflicted Copy" thing before in Dropbox.

I'm not doing anything to knowingly prompt this message.

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Does ArcGIS Pro have some autosave feature that tries to store things locally?

Nothing I can see suggests that's true, but I'm a recent convert.

Literally anything might help at this point. It's happening once every five-ten minutes.

Comment: Please provide error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.

Comment: You should try ArcGIS enterprise if you keep having the same problem.